# Output n-th element of the sequence

Tags: c++, sequence

So [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vbdC.png) is task.
I tried use this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i, n;
    cout<<"enter n ";
    cin>>n;
    if(n==1||n==2){
            i=1;
            cout<<"\n your number "<<i;
        } 
    else {
        for(i=3;i<=n;i++){
            i=(i-1)-4*(i-2);
        }
        cout<<"\n your number"<<i;
    }
    getch();
}
```

When enter 1 or 2, I get: ***"your number 1"***. But when I enter 3, 5, or 9, I get: ***"your number 11"***

- Where is mistake?
- And I can't use massive for this task,
  because size of massive must be constant number. Not variable
  ***n***. Am I right?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: `(i - 1)` does not give you the previous value...

Answer (score 0):

I thing that you've got -3 votes because you want us to find the mistake in your code.

As for your Question, you can use recursion:

```
int f(int x)
{
if(x==1||x==2)
    return 1;
else
    return =f(x-1)-4*(x-2);
}
int main(){
int x;
cin>>x;
cout<<f(x);
}
```

I recommend you always to use recursion in sequence when every term but some of the first terms depends on the previous terms.

Recursion will call the function for all terms and add the results to a stack on the memory. it's slower than your way; specially if you want to find the answer for more than one term. but here I thing it's more proper.

If you thought that `int` would be too small for the result, you could use `long long` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The way you tried to solve your task is incorrect. You shold keep only 2 last calculated elements in memory, let x(i-1) is a and x(i-2) is b. then you calculate your next value, which well be x(i - 1) on next iteration + move previous x(i-1) to x(i-2) - so your algorithms uses only constant amount of memory. Here is the code:

```
int calc(int n) {
  int a = 1, b = 1;
  for(n -= 2; n > 0; --n) {
      int tmp = a - 4 * b;
      b = a;
      a = tmp;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment previous answer, but in fact solution with recursion (if it is not tail-recursion) uses stack memory and it's amount is non-const

Comment: + there is a mistake there: f should return f(x-1) - 4 * f(x-2)